# How to install SecureSocial module in Play Framework 2.0.2?

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I got this module https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/ , and I don't even know how to make it work?

Comment: Check the User Guide at http://www.securesocial.ws. That should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

`SecureSocial` is delivered with [samples](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples) in both: `Java` and `Scala`, you should examine them and reproduce required elements.

I was testing samples last time and can ensure you that's good replacement for detailed documentation and `how-to's`

Comment: Well I dont find the documentation, just the README file, and that doesnt help me...

Comment: There is... _Copy the contents of the module-code into the modules/securesocial._ that means you have to create  folder `.../java/demo/modules/securesocial` and copy the files from https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/module-code into it.  Of course you need to clone whole repository into your disk. And please don't create another questions for the same topic.

Comment: Thanks for answer, But that didnt work I get that the package is not valid

Comment: This is what I did..

1. created a project with play new
2. copied all files and direktories from samples/java/demo
3 copied  https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/module-code to /modules/securesocial

Comment: Try: 1. clone from git whole securesocial repo, 2. go to java/demo folder, 3. create modules/securesocial folder and paste there files from module-code, 4. back to java/demo folder and start it with : play run.   That's the way I runned it. Of course you need to configure https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/conf/securesocial.conf and use your credentials for each required service.

Comment: I am having the same issue as Nolaeh. It keeps saying package not recognized.

Comment: this is ridiculous. there should be some sort of valuable documentation, or at least an attempt to answer the user's question? the play framework doco at https://playframework.com/modules/securesocial-0.2.4/home is so bad it's amazing.