# Where can I find installation manual for SecureSocial?

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

I got this link https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo and dont understand the README file, what to do. copy some file to where, the first thing.. I dont find which files or direktory to copy where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install SecureSocial module in Play Framwork 2.0.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677952/how-to-install-securesocial-module-in-play-framwork-2-0-2)

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question again and again. It's the third in two days. I also suggest you to post your question on the Play! mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/play-framework

Comment: well is not the same, in the other question I asked how to install, and I only got as answer to a page that I dont find anything on..

Answer (score 1):

There's a User Guide available at http://www.securesocial.ws.